# Basic Read CSV File Questions

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

Thanks in advance, C# newb here having a few issues.

I this CSV file provided daily, large, and has no header. I only need certain items out of this file.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            {
                HasHeaderRecord = false,
            };
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(iFile.FileName))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
            {
                var records = new List<BQFile>();
                csv.Read();
                csv.ReadHeader();

                while (csv.Read())
                {
                    var record = new BQFile()
                    {
                        SNumber = csv.GetField<string>("SNumber"),
                        FOBPoint = csv.GetField<string>("FOBPoint")

                    };
                }
```

What I am not understanding since this CSV files 150+ fields, is how do grab the correct data. For example, if SNumber is column 46, FOBPoint is column 123. I am finding the CSVHelper documentation a little limited to me.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If there is no header, then do you need to call csv.ReadHeader()? If you know the column index then there's no need to use headers or field names for anything. The file wouldn't know how to locate it. Use the indexes if you know them.

Comment: If you parse the string into a 2d array by newline and commas, then you can just access it directly. This might not be preferred depending on how big the file is. Otherwise you can just read your line and parse that into an array you can index.

Comment: *If you parse the string into a 2d array by newline and commas* - and then build in support for quoted fields, and mapping records to objects, and... Nah, just use a CSV reader :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I am not understanding since this CSV files 150+ fields, is how do grab the correct data

By index, because there is no header

In your BQFile, decorate the properties with an attribute of `[Index(NNN)]` where N is the column number (0-based). The `IndexAttribute` is found in `CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes` namespace - I mention this because Entity Framework also has an Index attribute; be sure you use the correct one

```
pubic class BQFile{
  [Index(46)]
  public string SNumber { get; set;}

  ...
}
```

Then do:

```
        var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        {
            HasHeaderRecord = false,
        };
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(iFile.FileName))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
        {
            var records = csv.GetRecords<BQFile>();

            ...
```

`records` is an *enumeration* on top of the file stream (via CSVHelper, which reads records as it goes and creates instances of BQFile). You can only enumerate it once, and then after you're done enumerating it the filestream will be at the end - if you wanted to re-read the file you'd have to Seek the stream or renew the `reader`.  Also, the file is only read (in chunks, progressively) *as you enumerate*. If you return `records` somewhere, so you drop out of the `using` and you thus dispose the reader, you'll get an error when you try to start reading from `records` (because it's disposed)

To work with `records`, you either `foreach` it, processing the objects you get as you go:

```
foreach(BQFile bqf in records){
  //do stuff with each BQFile here
}
```

Or if you want to load it all into memory, you can do something like `ToList()` it so you end up with a bunch of BQFile in a List, and then you can e.g. access them randomly, read them over and over etc..

```
var bqfs = records.ToList();
```

ps; I don't know, when you said "it's column 46" if that's counting from 1 or 0.. You might have to adjust your 46.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I have made it past that issue and on to the next. Now I have this issue:
"You can ignore bad data by setting BadDataFound to null."
Found the issue, just need to figure out how to fix it.
This is one line of the CSV which has a " included in it. How do I get around that?
"1060-00-DREV"B"